# Retrieve the extended propery Business Addresses in a exchange server soap request

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm having some troubles getting the BusinessAddressesArray property (extended property) from the exchange server (`version 2016`) for a `persona` via `soap` request. Here is the `XML` request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
    <soap:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2016" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <FindPeople xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
         <PersonaShape>
        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
         <t:AdditionalProperties>
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Address" PropertyType="StringArray" />
          <!-- Add other extended properties as needed -->
        </t:AdditionalProperties>
      </PersonaShape>
            <IndexedPageItemView BasePoint="Beginning" MaxEntriesReturned="1000" Offset="9000"/>
            <ParentFolderId>
                <t:FolderId Id="MY_FOLDER_ID"/>
            </ParentFolderId>
        </FindPeople>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It is mainly this part here:

```
<t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Address" PropertyType="StringArray" />
```

I'm not able to construct it in the propor way to be able to retrieve the businesses addresses of a persona.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I sorted it out by myself. Who ever faces this problem in the future, it seems that it is not possible to find out the business adddress using the `FindPeople` endpoint. After too many investigations I found the piece of data needed via the `GetItem` endpoint but under another property name: `PhysicalAddresses` which totally misled me all the time.

Here is an example of the XML soap request I did:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
    <soap:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2016" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
    <GetItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
      <ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>Default</t:BaseShape>
      </ItemShape>
      <ItemIds>
        <t:ItemId Id="YOUR_ITEM-OR-CONTACT_ID" ChangeKey="YOUR_CHANGE_KEY" />
      </ItemIds>
    </GetItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And here the response example:

```
 <t:PhysicalAddresses>
    <t:Entry Key="Business">
       <t:Street>TEST_STREET 22a</t:Street>
       <t:City>TEST_CITY</t:City>
       <t:CountryOrRegion>D</t:CountryOrRegion>
       <t:PostalCode>123456</t:PostalCode>
    </t:Entry>
 </t:PhysicalAddresses>
```

Also through the `EWS` service it can be retrieved like this:

```
var globalFolder = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.MyContacts);
var view = new ItemView(50, 0);
var items = await exchangeService.FindItems(globalFolder, view);

foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (item is Contact contact)
    {
        contact.PhysicalAddresses.TryGetValue(PhysicalAddressKey.Business, out var address);
        Console.WriteLine(address.City);

        Console.WriteLine($"Display Name: {contact.DisplayName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"First Name: {contact.GivenName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Last Name: {contact.Surname}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Company name: {contact.CompanyName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Company website: {contact.BusinessHomePage}");

        contact.EmailAddresses.TryGetValue(EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1, out var emailAddress1);
        Console.WriteLine($"Email 1: {emailAddress1.Address}");
    }
}
```